# Account for hasMany relationships in equals and hashCode

Tags: grails, equals, hashcode

I would like to use the [@EqualsAndHashCode](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/index.html?groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html) annotation on my domain classes, but it seems the `equals` and `hashCode` methods generated by that annotation don't take `hasMany` fields into account.  I don't see any way to change this with the annotation, but I'm hoping that I'm missing something because it is very convenient (if it works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Define the `hasMany` relationship as a `Set` in the parent domain class, which we normally do not do as it is redundant.
- You also have to make sure you are using `@EqualsAndHashCode` AST for the child domain.

For example:

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Parent {
    String name
    Integer age

    //Adding this as a property makes it a candidate for equals() and hashCode()
    Set<Child> children

    static hasMany = [children: Child]
}

@EqualsAndHashCode
class Child {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [parent : Parent]
}

//Unit Test
void testSomething() {
    def parent1 = new Parent(name: 'Test', age: 20).save()
    def child1 = new Child(name: 'Child1')
    parent1.addToChildren(child1)
    parent1.save()

    def parent2 = new Parent(name: 'Test', age: 20).save()
    def child2 = new Child(name: 'Child1')
    parent2.addToChildren(child2)
    parent2.save(flush: true)

    assert parent1 == parent2
    assert child1 == child2
}
```

In case, you are thinking of indexing hasMany items, then use `List` instead of `Set`.

Comment: What do you mean by "indexing" in your last comment? By default `hasMany` uses `Set` does it not? So if I just use set can I expect the same behavior I get from a typical Grails `hasMany` relationship?  Could you give an example of why I would want to use `List` instead of `Set`?

Comment: Yes correct, by default hasMany uses Set. In case you want to use as ordered children like children[0], children[1], ...  then you can  use it as a List. Refer [List Of Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps) in GORM documents.

Comment: @ubiquibacon Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Yeah, that is why I upvoted :)  I'll accept once my (multifaceted) problem is solved.  Guess you saw I called you out in a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345494/grails-unique-with-hasmany).

Comment: @ubiquibacon Yup I did. :)

Comment: Meh, after thinking about it you have answered this question, so I'll just accept.  If you have any ideas on my larger problem (other question I linked to) I would like to hear them.  Thanks!